# How do I convert config file to dict in Python?

Tags: python

```
server 192.168.10.10 443 {
    protocol TCP

    _server 192.168.10.1 443 {
        weight 1
        SSL_GET {
            url {
                path /
            }
            connect_timeout 3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What dictionary structure do you want? What have you tried so far? Have you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and the [Stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: How are the `server`-lines supposed to work? I can easily understand that in general the format is `key value`, but in the server lines we have `server IP port dict-value`...

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a full specification for the configuration files?

I am going to guess that what you posted is an example of one, however it's very easy to produce a naive parser that works on one example but not others using different features.

Also the dictionary structure that it is useful to get out of your parser depends very much on what you wish to use it for.

If you find out what standard this config file goes from you may also find that someone has done the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one already you're going to have to create a grammar and parse that into a Python object.  If you've never done this before, you're in for a lot of reading to get up to par!

My first suggestion to solve this would be to check out [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).